# Connection to MS Graph using Powershell and ADFv2 Web Activity Failing

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I can connect to MS Graph to get a Bearer token using Powershell but not with a Web Acvtivity in ADFv2 using the same credentials.

I'm getting the TenantId, ApplicationId and ClientSecret from an existing App in Azure.

[image]

This is what I'm doing in Powershell - Works

```
# Authenticate to Microsoft Graph
Write-Host "Authenticating to Microsoft Graph via REST method"
 
$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$restbody = @{
         grant_type    = 'client_credentials'
         client_id     = $applicationID
         client_secret = $clientSecret
         resource      = $resource
}
     
 # Get the return Auth Token
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Body $restbody
Write-Host "Authenticated - token retrieved of type " $($token.token_type)
```

Result

[image]

This is the Web Activity - Fails

```
Input
{
    "url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "body": "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=\"<applId>\"&client_secret=\"<client_secret>\"&resource=\"https://graph.microsoft.com/\"",
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
    }
}
```

Error

> Application with identifier '{appIdentifier}' was not found in the
> directory '{tenantName}'. This can happen if the application has not
> been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by
> any user in the tenant. You may have sent your authentication request
> to the wrong tenant.

The error doesn't make sense as it works in powershell.

The difference here is that I'm executing the powershell with my own account and with a System Assigned MI in ADF.  What permission am I missing?  How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'd try logging the request your making and check that you getting the correct tenantid as compared to Powershell. An easy mistake to make (I've done it myself) is mix the tenant and appid around which is what would give the error your getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce same thing in my environment got below results:

**PowerShell with Bearer token  :**

[image]

**To resolve the error  .Please follow below steps:**

**Step1:** Created AD application added permission as below:

[image]

**Step2:** Create  a web activity to get the Access Token from ADF

- URL: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant ID>/oauth2/token`

[image]

- **Method :** POST
- **Body:** `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/`
- **Header:** `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]

**Step3:** Create Set variable :

- Add dynamic content ->  `@activity('Web1').output.access_token`

[image]

**Response**

[image]