# API to retrieve QuickBooks Online General Ledger Data with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, api, azure-data-factory, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to use Azure Data Factory to connect to QuickBooks Online General Ledger using OAUTH2. My approach is to first create a pipeline with a Web Activity to perform a POST call to receive the authentication token, then create a Copy Activity to read a JSON returned from QuickBooks. My approach is based on this [blog.](https://www.alexvolok.com/2019/adfv2-rest-api-part1-oauth2) from Alex Volok Consultancy.

I have been unable to use the Web Activity successfully. I am unsure of the parameters and how to configure the Web Activity but have tried many different combinations trying to get this to work.

My desired result is to get QuickBooks Online data into Azure, is this the correct approach?

If this is not the best approach, what is?

If this is the correct approach, the attached screenshot shows my attempt at creating the Web Activity parameters to retrieve the authentication token that is currently not working. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Azure Data Factory Web Activity]

Comment: hi @Zee Please edit and provide your rest Api link .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below approach. It will solve your problem.

**Sample URL :** `http://restapi.adequateshop.com/api/authaccount/login`

> **Postman:**

Using Postman, I generated a bearer Token for testing.

[image]

I used the same URL with web Activity and generated a bearer Token in the Azure data factory.

Use Your **User id** and **Password** as Body.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

For more information refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095661/connection-to-ms-graph-using-powershell-and-adfv2-web-activity-failing/74109551#74109551) Thread and [Blog](https://www.appsloveworld.com/sample-rest-api-url-for-testing-with-authentication) by Ashok Patel